# file-notify support on OSX

Tags: osx

Is [Notifications on File Changes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Notifications.html) supported on Mac OS X? I can't seem to find any documentation about how to do this anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

For the records, support of kqueue has been added to the file notification libraries in the upcoming Emacs 25.1. This means, that you could use file notifications in Emacs under *BSD and OSX.

For OSX, FSEvents might be better suited. But nobody has taken the ball, and offered an implementation for Emacs.

Comment: Yay! Tried it on OS X (compiled from the git repository), and it works (using `file-notify-add-watch`). At least, in my superficial testing, it does.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is: no.

From [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.24.4):

> ** Emacs can now be compiled with file notification support. This happens by default if a suitable system library is found at build
>   time.  To prevent this, use the configure option
>   `--without-file-notification'.  See below for file-notify features.
>   This feature is not available for the Nextstep port.

Note that "Nextstep", in this context, means "OS X".  There's a lengthy explanation of this confusing terminology [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEXTSTEP).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP):

> [...] Apple's OS X and iOS are direct descendants of NeXTSTEP, through the
>   OPENSTEP lineage.

Quote 1 + quote 2 = Notification on file changes is not supported on Mac OSX.

Comment: okay; so basically, the answer is no.

Comment: This answer is missing an actual answer. Why does this quote answer the question? Is "Nexstep" a codename for OSX? Or is it just a case that OSX has no "suitable system library"?

Comment: @Malabarba http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP

Comment: @Nsukami_ Yes, that's how I inferred my second question. The answer can still use clarification. :-)

Comment: @Malabarba Ok, let me please edit my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

No, file notifications are not yet supported on Mac OS X, as detailed in the other answer.

I'd guess that one reason for that is that on earlier OS X versions, notifications were limited to telling you that something had changed in a certain directory; it wouldn't tell you *what* in that directory had changed.  Given that limitation, the API on the Emacs Lisp level would be rather inconsistent.

File-level notifications were introduced in 10.7 (Lion).  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1772209/113848) contains more details.  As I understand it, it should now be possible to implement this functionality for Emacs on OS X.